# How to retrieve organization list from MS dynamics CRM online using CRM SDK 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I am new to CRM. I want to know how to retrieve organization list from MS dynamics CRM online using CRM SDK 2011. I want to know how can I able to connect to MS Dynamics CRM online using CRM SDK 2011 and how can I able to retrieve it

It will be very helpful to me if you provide code to do this

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, Download the SDK and have a look at the code at following location:

`SDK\SampleCode\CS\QuickStart or SDK\SampleCode\VB\QuickStart`

Read through the following links:

[Run a Simple Program Using Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334689.aspx)

[Development for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309408.aspx)